# Is there a way to animate table columns in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a beamer presentation with a `tabular` environment. I want to expose the `tabular` environment column by column, on separate slides. I tried using `\pause` in the `tabular` header, or in the cells themselves, but they don't show a whole column at once. I want even the headers not to show until the next click. Is it possible to do that without having to copy partial tables into multiple frames?

(I also want each header of a new column appearing to be alerted, compared to the previous columns, but that's not a must if it is hard.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should take care of it. See [Beamer User Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) section 9.6.3 for `\action`. Section 9.3 and others talk about `\onslide`, but that won't handle alerts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\aheader}[2]{\action<#1-|alert@#1>{#2}}
% first argument: slide number to appear from, second argument: content of header 
\newcommand{\hiddencell}[2]{\action<#1->{#2}}
% first argument: slide number to appear from, second argument: content of cell

\begin{document}
\frame{
Here's my table:
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\aheader{2}{Column A} & \aheader{3}{Column B} & \aheader{4}{Column C} \\
\hiddencell{2}{1} &     \hiddencell{3}{2} &     \hiddencell{4}{3} \\
\hiddencell{2}{4} &     \hiddencell{3}{5} &     \hiddencell{4}{6} \\
\hiddencell{2}{7} &     \hiddencell{3}{8} &     \hiddencell{4}{9}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this still keeps the table borders, if there are any (I use borders between cells). is there a way to make them appear only when needed, when the column shows?

Comment: Section 23.5 of the User Guide reads "When you wish to uncover a table line-by-line, you will run into all sorts of problems if there are vertical and horizontal lines in the table," and gives the reasons why. It recommends using the colortbl package instead. I'm trying to break the habit of excessive vertical rules (and horizontal ones) in my tables, and sticking with the designs given in the booktabs package.